# Add a separate HTML file into create-react-app

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, create-react-app

I know react is for Single Page Application. I have already build a complete application. I have a particular 3rd party integration that requires javascript and css files. I cannot add those external scripts as it breaks my entire application by overriding css and js.

I need to have a separate admin.html file which can have its own css and javascript tags. I do not want any conflict with my react app which renders on `index.html`

I tried to eject create-react-app and add a new admin.html.
https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/1084#issuecomment-568550609

But it uses only one page(index.html). This will not help me because I need completely a separate html file which I can import any javascript or css freely without any conflict on my `index.html`

Currently the possibility I thought was to create a separate react application just to render to this `admin.html`. So that there won't be any conflicts between javascript and css. But I want to know if there is an alternate way that I can achieve it in `create-react-app`. If so, simple example would be greatly appreciated.

PS: I need to redirect from one of components in my application to this new view `admin.html` with some data

Comment: can you handle the admin route through a nodejs bff?

Comment: I'm using a REST API as a backend. Therefore I do not understand how to make it happen as you mentioned.

Comment: https://create-react-app.dev/docs/deployment/#other-solutions

app.get('/admin', (req, res) => res.sendFile(adminHtmlPath));
app.get('/*', (req, res) => res.sendFile(reactHtmlPath));

Comment: No, this is not possible for me as I deploy my front-end application separate. I have a react application and a backend API. There is no Node server that serves my requests. In my frontend there will a node server spinned up by create-react-app. But this is something create-react-app internally manages.